# How can I merge cells same data in Excel 2010?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I need to merge cells containing the same information and I'm new to Excel, so I could really use some help. Here's my situation. I was given 3 spreadsheets. The first with a User ID and a Department. The second has a User ID, First and Last name, and the third has a User ID and Roles. They aren't lined up in the same column, and I need to merge the User ID's into Column A and the other information to be in the same row without jumbling the information.

To explain it another way, if the User ID in Column A matches a User ID in column D, I need Column D to merge with the cell containing the ID in Column A. Then I need the correct First name, Last name, Department, and any roles associated with that User ID to be placed in their respective places in that row. Please help!

This is what the current spreadsheet looks like. The information I received in each spreadsheet is separated by black columns, but will be deleted. I put those in to understand where each set of data came from.

[image]
[full image](https://imgur.com/r5XBlJu)

This is what I want it to look like. The 2nd and 3rd role are only to be filled if a person has a 2nd/3rd role.

[image]
[full image](https://imgur.com/6QdAFKY)

Comment: So what we are seeing in the top image is data that is actually separated into three worksheets? Looking at the top image is it correct to think that columns A & B are columns A & B on sheet one, columns D - F are columns A - C on Sheet two, and columns H & I are columns A & B on sheet 3? Finally is it correct to think that the user ID column on sheet2 is the one that needs to be used on Sheet4 column C?

Comment: Semi-correct. The data is originally in 3 worksheets, but I've combined it into 1 and separated them by changing the fill color to Black. That will be deleted before I input the code, though.


You are correct on the columns. A & B are A & B on Sheet 1, D - F are A - C on Sheet 2, and H - I are columns A - C on Sheet 3. The user ID is fake and won't be used at all. It was merely an example. I need the last names on sheet one to be in Column A, first names to be Column B, User ID as Column C, and so on. As you can see, the User Names aren't on the same rows and therein lies my problem.

Comment: I am confused by the two statements: "The user ID is fake and won't be used at all" and "User ID as Column C". Never the less I am going to post my answer, and perhaps we can adjust from there.

Comment: My apologies. What I meant is that the user ID "mmarkl95" in the second picture is fake. The other User ID's in the first image are all real and true. 

What I meant by "User ID as Column C" is that I want my finished product to resemble the second image, with Column A containing all of the last names, Column B containing the first names, Column C showing the User ID, Column D showing the department, Column E showing the first role, Column F showing the second role (If one exists on the spreadsheet), and Column G showing the third role (If one exists on the spreadsheet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the steps I used to tackled the problem:

- Populate C2 and down (by dragging the fill handle) with the formula `=Sheet2!A2`
- Populate B2 and down (by double clicking the fill handle) with the
  formula `=INDEX(Sheet2!B:B,MATCH(C2,Sheet2!A:A,0))`
- Populate A2 and down (by double clicking the fill handle) with the
  formula `=INDEX(Sheet2!C:C,MATCH(C2,Sheet2!A:A,0))`
- Populate D2 and down (by double clicking the fill handle) with the
  formula `=INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,MATCH(C2,Sheet1!A:A,0))`
- Populate E2 with the formula
  `=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet3!$B:$B,SMALL(IF(Sheet3!$A:$A=$C2,ROW(Sheet3!$A:$A)),COLUMNS($E2:E2))),"")`
  which will need to be entered with `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter` as it is an
  array formula.
- With cell E2 still selected drag the fill handle across to cells F2
  and G2.
- With cells E2, F2 and G2 still selected, double click the fill handle
  to send the formulas down.

Comment: Great. Thank you so much. One question though. When I input the code into column B, it changed to '0'. Was I supposed to put cell references in the B:B and A:A part?

Comment: No, you should not have to put cell references in. The `Sheet2!B:B` part is finding the first name of the person who has the ID listed in column C. The `Sheet2!A:A` is finding the matching ID and reporting what row it is on. Now that I think about it there is probably an easier way to get the first and last names. Since we got the ID numbers straight from sheet2, then on Sheet4 we could populate A2 and down with `=Sheet2!C2` and B2 and down with `=Sheet2!B2`. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I've noticed that some User ID's have up to 4 different departments and up to 3 different roles. Since I have to have 1 User ID per row, could you share a code to complete this? I've been trying to figure one out for the past day, but have come up with nothing.

The new layout will be:
[Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/D5JntfD.jpg)

Comment: Same principle as with the Roles, only we are now directing the formula to find values in sheet1 instead of sheet3. Paste this formula, `=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$B:$B,SMALL(IF(Sheet1!$A:$A=$C2,ROW(Sheet1!$A:$A)),COLUMNS($D2:D2))),"")` into cell D2, use `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter` to enter, drag the fill handle over to cell G2, and while all four cells are still selected double click to send the formulas down.